# How to parse multiple selected files to function

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Since the version 1.20 (January 18) it is possible to select multiple files in the explorer on the left side.

If I select multiple files I would like to parse them into a method of my extension. Currently, I get only the primary file (on which the action was performed)...

```
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.testClass', function (file) {

}));
```

How can I get a array of all selected files?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65257167/836330 for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**The second argument**

`context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.testClass', 
  function (file, files) {
       console.log(files)
  }))`