# Get focused Explorer folder or file in an extension when command triggered by a shortcut, not by context menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

A follow-on to this question: [How to get file name or path in vscode extension when user right click on file in explorer/context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961457/how-to-get-file-name-or-path-in-vscode-extension-when-user-right-click-on-file-i/51971599#51971599)

My command expects to receive the uri to the item selected with a right-click; and in fact it does if I invoke the command by choosing it from the context menu....

If, however, I bind a shortcut key to this command (and correctly set the "when" context to only activate when explorer has focus) I do **not** receive the uri; that parameter is `undefined`.

Obviously there are plenty of "built-in" commands ("Reveal in File Explorer" -- Shift+Alt+R) that function they way I would like my own to command operate.

What's the trick to getting the uri to my own command when invoked with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: `Reveal in File Explorer` is executed when the active editor has focus

Comment: Is the file or folder you are interested in focussed in the Explorer when you trigger the keybinding?  If yes, there may be a way to do what you want.  Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

There is a hint in a related issue: [Get selected file/folder in the Explorer view](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3553).

It is suggested to use

`vscode.commands.executeCommand('copyFilePath');`

see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3553#issuecomment-438969485

so I investigated that and it can work like this:

```js
async function activate(context) {

   let createFile = vscode.commands.registerCommand('folder-operations.createFile', async (folder) => {

    // use this if triggered by a menu item,
    let newUri = folder;  // folder will be undefined when triggered by keybinding

     if (!folder) {                       // so triggered by a keybinding
       await vscode.commands.executeCommand('copyFilePath');
       folder = await vscode.env.clipboard.readText();  // returns a string

       // see note below for parsing multiple files/folders
       newUri = await vscode.Uri.file(folder);          // make it a Uri 
     }

     createFileOpen(newUri);                 // use in some function  
  });
  context.subscriptions.push(createFile);
}
```

### NOTE :

This works when multiple folders or files are selected as well.  Then `folder = await vscode.env.clipboard.readText();` will return something like (on W10):

`"C:\\Users\\Mark\\OneDrive\\Test Bed\\zip\r\nC:\\Users\\Mark\\OneDrive\\Test Bed\\zipMultiple"`

when two folders, `zip` and `zipMultiple` in this case, are selected and then the keybinding is triggered for the `folder-operations.createFile` command.  So you would have to parse/split that string to get the two folders selected.  Same with multiple files.

---

---

Using some keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+c",
  "command": "folder-operations.createFile",
  "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder && filesExplorerFocus"
}
```

Now this will work when some folder is focused in the Explorer and you trigger your keybinding.  Demo creating a new file by keybinding:

[image: get folder path in an extension via a keybinding]

Comment: dont use `vscode.Uri.parse` it handles file paths with `#` incorrect and it might handle Window paths incorrect, use `vscode.Uri.file`

Comment: I am on W10, I haven't seen an issue there.  But thanks, I cleaned up the code and used your advice.  @rioV8

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you get with your `keybindings.json` defined key binding is the `args` property of the key binding.

In VSC the key bindings are defined different. The command is a function of the key binding and it gets special arguments.

In file `src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/electron-browser/fileActions.contribution.ts`

```
const REVEAL_IN_OS_COMMAND_ID = 'revealFileInOS';

KeybindingsRegistry.registerCommandAndKeybindingRule({
  id: REVEAL_IN_OS_COMMAND_ID,
  weight: KeybindingWeight.WorkbenchContrib,
  when: EditorContextKeys.focus.toNegated(),
  primary: KeyMod.CtrlCmd | KeyMod.Alt | KeyCode.KEY_R,
  win: {
    primary: KeyMod.Shift | KeyMod.Alt | KeyCode.KEY_R
  },
  handler: (accessor: ServicesAccessor, resource: URI | object) => {
    const resources = getMultiSelectedResources(resource, accessor.get(IListService), accessor.get(IEditorService), accessor.get(IExplorerService));
    revealResourcesInOS(resources, accessor.get(IElectronService), accessor.get(INotificationService), accessor.get(IWorkspaceContextService));
  }
});
```

In extensions we can't get an object that has the focus.

So the extension has no way of getting the "TreeView" of the File Explorer.

`vscode.window` also does not allow us to get to some of the GUI elements.