# How can i get the uri when using a key binding to exec command

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have a command to generate template files, i set a explorer/context menu to exec the command. But how can i get the uri when using a key binding to exec command. Some extension's author use the activeTextEditor to get the active file uri, but i think this not the optimality.

I try to search API doc.

Comment: You want to get the selected files in the Explorer when you use a keybinding to trigger a command?

Comment: Yes, just like the keybinding of delete.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65257167/836330 I think that is still the only way to do that from a keybinding (which returns nothing to indicate what is currently selected in the explorer upon keybinding trigger).