# Not able to get uri from file explorer in Vscode?

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I am creating one vscode extension which creates new file from where that command is executed. When I use that through context menu then I'm able to get the folder path/uri and creates the file but when I use shortcut that ctrl+n then my uri comes out to be undefined..

I'm registering my command like this

```
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('template-gen.createNewFile', (uri: vscode.Uri) => {
        let filePath = uri ? uri.fsPath : getActiveFolderPath();;
        if(filePath !== null && filePath !== undefined)
        {
            fileModel.createFile(filePath);
        }
        
    }));
```

My manefiest file is binding the key..

```
"commands": [
      {
        "command": "template-gen.createNewFile",
        "title": "New template",
        "category": "Files and Folder"
      }

"menus": {
      "explorer/context": [
        {
          "command": "template-gen.createNewFile",
          "group": "navigation@-createFileFolder"
        }
      ]
    },
    "keybindings":{
      "command": "template-gen.createNewFile",
      "key": "ctrl+n",
      "mac": "cmd+n",
      "when": "explorerViewletFocus && filesExplorerFocus"
    }
```

I tried getting path through active folder but it is giving me root directory..

```
function getActiveFolderPath(): string | undefined {
    const activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    if (activeEditor && activeEditor.document) {
      const folderPath = vscode.workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(activeEditor.document.uri)?.uri.fsPath;
      if (folderPath) {
        return folderPath;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

How can I get the path from where I triger the shortcut like select src folder and press ctrl+n Then get path like thise user:/abc/DEveloper/project/exp/src?

Comment: I think you still have to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62945928/get-focused-explorer-folder-or-file-in-an-extension-when-command-triggered-by-a/65257167#65257167.  The accompanying issue is still open.