# Is it possible to get the currently selected directory of the vs code explorer as a variable?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

## The Goal

I'm trying to get the currently selected directory path in vscode as a variable from inside my `tasks.json` like below:

```
  {
    "label": "Echo selected directory from explorer",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "echo",
    "args": [
      "${selectedExplorerDirectory}",// Should return the path of the selected folder from the explorer
    ],
    "problemMatcher": []
  }
```

## Issue

As for the [predefined variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables) doesn't offer the possibility to get the selected directory path from the explorer. It only offers variables like `${cwd}` or `${workspaceFolder}` which returns the project folder. Also `${relativeFileDirname}` only returns the path of the currently opened file, which is not what I'm looking for.

## Question

Is there any way to obtain the currently selected directory as a variable so I can use it in the `tasks.json` file?

Comment: loosely related (not a dup target): https://stackoverflow.com/q/62945928/11107541

Comment: if VSC does not provide that variable an extension would not help you because there is no callback on selection in the explorer. Only when using the explorer context menu and selecting a command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

After the answer of @rioV8 I decided to create and publish my own VSCode Extension called [AngularExplorerContext](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=creative-house-org.angularexplorercontext) which adds two new options to the explorer context menu when right-clicking on a folder.

[image: AngularExplorerContext showcase]

It eliminates the need of typing the `ng generate` command in to the terminal and the usage of this extension is pretty much straight forward.

I meanwhile also added a second context option to be able to add arguments to the generation process and the NG Types from the dropdown can now be customized using the settings window of VSCode.

[image: Custom NG Types]

I hope this will help anyone in the future trying to improve their workflow with the ng generation process.

The extension can be found on the official [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=creative-house-org.angularexplorercontext). Feel free to let me know if you come across any issues so I can make improvements to this extension!